# How to break sizes/number into an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, numbers

I have an online shop, and this shop display, clothes, shoe and so on... For shoes I have a checkbox of sizes like this: "size": "36,37,38", but this is in the JSON, and in the browser, in the browser, it's like this pic below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rD26.png

I need to break these sizes into an object to display each size in a separate checkbox.
like this
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY6Db.png

if anyone can help?
thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on the comma character to get an array of sizes. Then you can use that array to produce the html you need with a map. Finally use the join method with an empty string to insert the content with innerHTML.

```js
const data = {
  sizes: '36,37,38',
}

const sizes = data.sizes.split(',')
const sizesList = sizes.map(size => `<span class="item">${size}</span>`)

document.querySelector('#main').innerHTML = sizesList.join('')
```

```css
#main {
  margin: 30px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, Bro thanks for your answer. this is exactly what I am looking for. but I have another problem that I'm getting this data from a JSON file. how to use instant of this code:  sizes: '36,37,38', 
the code that comes from json?

Comment: It depends a lot on where the json comes from. If it's a file you might be able to import it, depends on the setup of your app. If it's coming from an API you'll need to fetch it and then use it, again exactly how to do this depends a lot on your setup. Try making a new question with some details about your app and where the json is coming from

Comment: Yes, the JSON data coming from an API, and I am using that APi